# TADOQuery Loses XML Fields

Tags: delphi, ado

When I use use Delphi XE2 or XE10 and ADO to pull data from SQL Server 2008 R2 using the **SQL Server Native Client 10.0** provider, XML fields are lost and any fields that come after the XML field are inaccessible.  To illustrate:

1. Create a new VCL project
2. Drop a `TADOConnection` and `TADOQuery` on the form
3. Setup the `TADOConnection` to attach to a SQL Server database
4. Set the `.Connection` property of the `TADOQuery` to the `TADOConnection`
5. Drop a button on the form and set its `OnClick()` event to be:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADOConnection1.Open;
  try
    ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := Concat(
      'create table #temp(str1 varchar(255), xml_data xml, str2 varchar(255)) ',
      'insert into #temp values (''string 1'', ''<data>xml</data>'', ''string 2'') ',
      'select * from #temp ',
      'drop table #temp'
    );
    ADOQuery1.Open;
    ShowMessage(ADOQuery1.FieldByName('str1').AsString);
    try
      ShowMessage(ADOQuery1.FieldByName('xml_data').AsString);
    except
      on e: Exception do
        ShowException(e, ExceptAddr); // trap error and show extra error info
    end;
    try
      ShowMessage(ADOQuery1.FieldByName('str2').AsString);
    except
      on e: Exception do
        ShowException(e, ExceptAddr); // show extra error info
    end;
  finally
    ADOConnection1.Close;
  end;
end;
```

My connection string for the `TADOConnection` is `Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;User ID="";Initial Catalog=tempdb;Data Source=localhost;Initial File Name="";Server SPN=""`, all other properties of `TADOConnection` and `TADOQuery` are the defaults when you drop them on the form.

---

When I run the app and click <kbd>Button 1</kbd>, I get one message box and two errors:

[image: Message Box]

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

The XML field (`xml_data`) is not found.  And all fields that come after the XML field always return **Multi-step operations generated errors.  Check each status value.** (even if I don't try to access the `xml_data` field).

I tried using **Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server** and it fixes the issue.  However, I have read elsewhere that the OLE DB provider has issues with date fields, so I want to use the **SQL Server Native Client 10.0** provider if possible.

---

What is the trick to get ADO to receive a XML field from the database so that it is properly defined in `TADOQuery.FieldDefs` when using **SQL Server Native Client 10.0**?

Comment: I have a vague recollection of reading about problems with XML fields.  Does the problem remain if you make the XML column the last one in the table?

Comment: @whosrdaddy - Don't know why my searches didn't find that.  Thank you!  If you want to post as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Comment: No problem, no need for an answer as it is an exact dupe ;)